# Completeness of Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, differential-topology, complete-spaces, function-spaces

Consider the set $C^k(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^m})$ in the metric $\rho$ where $\rho$ is defined by $$\rho(f,g)=\sup\{d(f(x),g(x)),d(f^1(x),g^1(x)),\dots ,d(f^k(x),g^k(x))|x\in \mathbb{R^n}\}.$$

How can I show, $(C^k(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^m}),\rho)$ is not a complete metric space? Also if we consider $C^\infty(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^m})$ in the metric $\rho$,where
$$\rho(f,g)=\sup\{d(f(x),g(x)),d(f^1(x),g^1(x)),\dots,d(f^k(x),g^k(x)),\dots|x\in \mathbb{R^n}\}$$
then how to show that $(C^\infty(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^m}),\rho)$ is not complete? I am completely stuck. Please help!

Comment: For future reference: Write entire mathematical expressions, not just individual symbols, in math mode. In other words, write `$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$` (which yields "$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$") instead of `f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10` which yields a much uglier "f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10"

Comment: Your $\rho(f, g)$ might not be even a finite number. So it is not a metric.

Comment: Have you looked at examples? For instance,  taking $m=n=1$ and $k=0$, what is $\rho(1,x)$?